# How to import product Video programmatically with the use of custom script in magento 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2, product, custom, media, product-video

[image: default add video button][image]I import all product by custom script. but I'm not able to import the product video programmatically.
Basically, I have youtube link of videos. I can put url the using admin panel but I have 3000 product so, i can't do that way. I want to add Video progrmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like addImageMedieGallery function we should extend the
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor for adding video to product gallery,

```
product =  $this->productRepository->get($sku);
$videoData = [
            'video_id' => "test1", 
            'video_title' => "title", 
            'video_description' => "description",
            'thumbnail' => "image path", 
            'video_provider' => "youtube",
            'video_metadata' => null,
            'video_url' => "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=test",
            'media_type' => \Magento\ProductVideo\Model\Product\Attribute\Media\ExternalVideoEntryConverter::MEDIA_TYPE_CODE,
        ];
$videoData['file'] = $videoData['video_id'] . 'filename.jpg';  //download thumbnail image and save locally under pub/media
f ($product->hasGalleryAttribute())
        {
            $this->videoGalleryProcessor->addVideo(
                $product,
                $videoData,
                ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'],
                false,
                true
            );
        }
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

> $this->videoGalleryProcessor ( create an custom file for video process that extend the \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor )

We have to create Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Gallery\Video\Processor file in our module.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Gallery\Video;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
class Processor extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler
     */
    protected $createHandler;
    /**
     * Processor constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database       $fileStorageDb
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config              $mediaConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem                            $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery     $resourceModel
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler     $createHandler
     */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $fileStorageDb,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config $mediaConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery $resourceModel,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler $createHandler
) {
    parent::__construct($attributeRepository, $fileStorageDb, $mediaConfig, $filesystem, $resourceModel);
    $this->createHandler = $createHandler;
}
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @param array                          $videoData
 * @param [type]                         $mediaAttribute
 * @param boolean                        $move
 * @param boolean                        $exclude
 */
public function addVideo(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    array $videoData,
    $mediaAttribute = null,
    $move = false,
    $exclude = true
)
{
    $file = $this->mediaDirectory->getRelativePath($videoData['file']);
    if (!$this->mediaDirectory->isFile($file))
    {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('The image does not exist.'));
    }
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($file);
    $imgExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
    if (!isset($pathinfo['extension']) || !in_array(strtolower($pathinfo['extension']), $imgExtensions))
    {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Please correct the image file type.'));
    }
    
    $fileName = \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader::getCorrectFileName($pathinfo['basename']);
    $dispretionPath = \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader::getDispretionPath($fileName);
    $fileName = $dispretionPath . '/' . $fileName;
    
    $fileName = $this->getNotDuplicatedFilename($fileName, $dispretionPath);
    $destinationFile = $this->mediaConfig->getTmpMediaPath($fileName);
    try {
        /** @var $storageHelper \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database */
        $storageHelper = $this->fileStorageDb;
        if ($move)
        {
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile($file, $destinationFile);
            //Here, filesystem should be configured properly
            $storageHelper->saveFile($this->mediaConfig->getTmpMediaShortUrl($fileName));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->mediaDirectory->copyFile($file, $destinationFile);
            $storageHelper->saveFile($this->mediaConfig->getTmpMediaShortUrl($fileName));
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('We couldn\'t move this file: %1.', $e->getMessage()));
    }
    $fileName = str_replace('\\', '/', $fileName);
    $attrCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    $mediaGalleryData = $product->getData($attrCode);
    $position = 0;
    if (!is_array($mediaGalleryData))
    {
        $mediaGalleryData = ['images' => []];
    }
    foreach ($mediaGalleryData['images'] as &$image)
    {
        if (isset($image['position']) && $image['position'] > $position)
        {
            $position = $image['position'];
        }
    }
    $position++;
    unset($videoData['file']);
    $mediaGalleryData['images'][] = array_merge([
        'file' => $fileName,
        'label' => $videoData['video_title'],
        'position' => $position,
        'disabled' => (int)$exclude
    ], $videoData);
    $product->setData($attrCode, $mediaGalleryData);
    if ($mediaAttribute !== null)
    {
        $product->setMediaAttribute($product, $mediaAttribute, $fileName);
    }
    $this->createHandler->execute($product);
    return $fileName;
}
}
```

Hope this will help you , Thanks.

Comment: What do I put in value_id? Because randomly putting value is the wrong way to do it. Is there any way to fetch the last insert ID. and tell what path is set in the thumbnail? The Thumbnail path is for where we save the image or already saved image path.

Comment: For value I'd is auto generated and for thumbnail image its save the image path.

Comment: I set everything confused in 2 attributes (' thumbnail','$videoData['file']'). What I fill in these fields
My Image path is "/home/adminmaster/public_html/pub/media/catalog/product/2877vdo.jpg."
please help with this

Because error comes:
Product SKU: 24877. The image does not exist.

Comment: Please, if you know the answer, tell me.

Comment: Use pub media folder path , not use the SKU for this.Luke filename is absdc.jpg as a/b/absdc.jpg

Comment: Yes, 2877vdo.jpg is my file name, and my image path is pub/media/catalog/product/2877vdo.jpg; now my question is, what do I fill in the "thumbnail" attribute and $videodata[file] variable? Like currently, I fill In the thumbnail attribute as pub/media/catalog/product/2877vdo.jpg and in $videodata[file] = 277vdo.jpg But given an error, the image does  not exist

Comment: Got it, please provide relative path  of media folder like "catalog/product/2877vdo.jpg" and remove thumbnail key from video data
'thumbnail' => "image path",  // remove this

Comment: Yes, the video is uploaded now, but my additional image is not uploaded because of this script.

Answer (score 0):

Create an product custom attribute if you are not created earlier for youtube link.
Use your custom script or cron, loop through the products and initiate product Repository interface "**Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface**" and get the product by SKU or Magento product id and set the values for **video_url** and **video_title** attribute value respectively and save the product repository.

Before that please ensure you added youtube API Key
[image]

Sample code snippet as ,

```
private $productRepository; 
...
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
}

public function loadMyProduct($sku,$youtubeLink) {
    $product =  $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    $product->setData('video_url', 'video url');
    $product->setData('video_title', 'video title');
    $this->productRepository->save($product);
}
```

Comment: There are Magento default features to add the video. Why make the other attributes

Comment: I thought you were going by custm attribute. please try with default attribute code here

Comment: There is no default attribute code showing.

Comment: Please, if you know the answer, tell me.

Comment: Answer section is updated now. please check and revert if this helpful .

Comment: Magneto has an inbuilt field for video URLs same as the image I uploaded a picture check question again. There is no need to create custom attributes.

Comment: Is there any solution like we do for setName same as for the video?

Comment: For the image, addimagemediagallery function like this.